# Cannot create user profile service...Creating Profile Service Application. Please wait

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

[image]When I try to create a new user profile service application, it is stuck at Creating Profile Service Application. Please wait.

Eventually it times out. Any assistance would be appreciated.

It is a SharePoint 2013 environment patched with July 2018 CU and I have an App server and 2xWFE servers

[image]

the timer job appears to be stuck and does not run successfully:
 Get-SPTimerJob -Identity d47cf364-2cf7-4b91-b8ad-c9df48877ebe | fl
Description                 : Provisions service applications on a server.
DisplayName                 : Service Application Instance Provisioning Job
Service                     : UserProfileService
WebApplication              :
Server                      :
LockType                    : None
Schedule                    :
Title                       : Service Application Instance Provisioning Job
LastRunTime                 : 9/4/2018 5:47:02 PM

Comment: I'd be interested in this too. We recently removed our User Profile Services from SP 2013 On-Prem as it stopped working entirely in our last CU (I think it was July, too?) and it removes a lot of useful functionality...

Comment: could you please check the ULS logs / Event log for more clue? their are many reasons for it

Comment: nothing in the ULS logs or event logs that could point to root cause (yet). I do have a new finding - when creating the user profile service, it completes the creation of it only when I restart the timer service on my app server. Not sure why. But the user profile does not function or open after that

Comment: the timer job appears to be stuck and does not run successfully:
 Get-SPTimerJob -Identity d47cf364-2cf7-4b91-b8ad-c9df48877ebe | fl
Description                 : Provisions service applications on a server.
DisplayName                 : Service Application Instance Provisioning Job
Service                     : UserProfileService
WebApplication              :
Server                      :
LockType                    : None
Schedule                    :
Title                       : Service Application Instance Provisioning Job
LastRunTime                 : 9/4/2018 5:47:02 PM

Comment: uls log says - Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Few possible reasons,

1) your logged in user does not have correct privileges

2) check for same GUID displayed in ULS logs or network issues

3) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/scottstewart/2014/10/30/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-service-stuck-on-starting/

4) https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/44898d06-6b45-45e4-99c6-13c626a51907/user-profile-synchronization-service-stuck-on-starting?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure SharePoint Timer service is running on all SharePoint servers. Then recreate again.

If this issue still exists, you can try to create user profile service application via PowerShell cmdlet:
[PowerShell to Create User Profile Service application](http://sharepoint-learners.blogspot.com/2017/10/powershell-to-create-user-profile.html)

[A similar thread](http://davidmsterling.blogspot.com/2016/06/sharepoint-2016-timeout-trying-to.html) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by clearing the timer cache and creating a MyHost web app and site collection which is required by the user profile service

i also used a script to create the UPS which seemed to work alot better than usign the GUI